# How fusion reactor could be operated on space craft?

Tags: rocket-science, fusion, propulsion, space-mission

Considering that space craft uses engines only during acceleration and deceleration, how fusion reactor will be operated?
For example:

- it will be started / stopped for each maneuver
- will be working on full power all time
- scale down its output?

Comment: The problem is that we don't know yet with certainty what is the minimum size for a functional non-self-gravitational fusion reactor.

Comment: @lurscher "non-self gravitational fusion reactor".  Nice.  Must remember that one. :-)